# Reference request: classification of all representations of matrix algebra $\text{M}_n(k)$ in $k$-vector spaces up to isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces, representation-theory

As the question title suggests, where can I find the classification of all representations of the matrix algebra $\text{M}_n(k)$ in $k$-vector spaces up to isomorphism?

Any help would be well-appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: They're all isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $k^n$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is there any place where I can find this worked out?

Comment: Adding as a comment that this is one example of the general phenomenon of [Morita Equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence#Definition). This case is so fundemetal that is infact worked out, similarly to as below, on the page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is worked out in Chapter 28 of Lorenz's Algebra II (for example). The theorems in that book are labeled by F1,F2,F3,... for some reason.

Since $M_n(k)$ is a semisimple algebra (by F8), every representation of (module over) $M_n(k)$ is semisimple (by F13) and therefore a direct sum of simple modules (by F10), each of which is either $0$ or has the form $M_n(k) \cdot x = k^n$ for some $x \in k^n \backslash \{0\}$ (by F7).

In other words, it's a sum of copies of $k^n$.